# Relating/adding data to a django object list

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble understanding how to relate additional information to an existing Django list and if I should be doing this in my templates or in the view somehow. Please see the below scenario:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

For example in my view I am retrieving a list of all sports games and returning them:

```
def get_teams(request):

    teams = Team.objects.all()

    context = RequestContext(request, {
            'teams': teams,
        })
        return context
```

I would like to add some stats to the teams which I can then access in my template in the below fashion:

```
def get_teams(request):

    teams = Team.objects.all()

    for team in teams:
        team_win_percent(team)
        team_lose_percent(team)

    context = RequestContext(request, {
            'teams': teams,
        })
        return context


def team_win_percent(team)
    team_win_rate = [calculations here]

    return team_win_rate

def team_lose_percent(team)
    team_lose_rate = [calculations here]

    return team_lose_rate
```

What I am struggling to understand is how to add team_win_percentage and team_lose_percentage to my teams list so I can reference them in my template?

Any guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also for a few number of records append some field to the model query result the will be accessible from the template

```
class Team(models.Model): 
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


def get_teams(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    for team in teams:
        team.team_win_percent = calculate_team_win(team)
        team.team_lose_percent = calculate_team_loss(team)
    ....
```

In template

```
{% for team in teams %}
    team win percentage = {{ team.team_win_percent }}
    team lose percentage = {{ team.team_lose_percent }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this pointed me down the right path of what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this as as a model method;

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def team_win_percent(self):
        #self = team object
        team_win_rate = [calculations here]

        return team_win_rate

    def team_lose_percent(self):
        #self = team object
        team_lose_rate = [calculations here]

        return team_lose_rate
```

In template:

```
{% for team in teams %}
    team win percentage = {{ team.team_win_percent }}
    team lose percentage = {{ team.team_lose_percent }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I might actually be calling those calculations from more than one place so am wondering if it is a good idea to avoid putting logic in the code for the database/models and if it was best practice to keep everything  in the views?

Comment: Best practice is to keep logic in models

Comment: Serious question - what are views used for if logic is meant to be kept in models? Obviously templates are the user interface